# UV editing + texture - change color of the PNG image (caption)

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

I am using UV editing to put a letter to a wall. I have png like this:
[image]

After UV editing and and some texture added my output is like this:

[image]

I am looking for a way to change its color to some other one (and for example use Emission or sth like this).

My current nodes:

[image]

Comment: use your Image Texture as a mask: plug it into the Factor of a Mix Shader between a Diffuse and another one (or an Emission)

Comment: can you provide some example or some schema? Or YouTube tutorial? Mask is some node as well?

Comment: no it is not a node, if you plug an Image Texture (or Noise or else) into the factor of a Mix Shader, it will act as a mask between the 2 nodes that you will plug into the Mix Shader, give a try  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll find [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447) a long and complete answer to your question.

To make it short, here is how you could organize your nodes if you want to use your image texture as a kind of mask between an emission node and your wave background: Plug the "Hello" *Image Texture* into the Factor of a *Mix Shader*, and plug what you want into the 2 sockets of your *Mix Shader*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/31447) explains the concept.

Comment: yes, mine is a short answer  ;)

Comment: Well, thanks for taking the time and posting the proper setup. I personally don't mind. However, your answer just *solves the actual problem* and in this case there already is this [awesome answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447), which allows to understand the concepts easily... and is clearly a duplicate btw. In every sense it's worth it having a link around so posted as comment and I'm sure your answer benefit from that (even more if you would add it to your answer IMO).

Comment: you're right, I've edited my answer